# JQuery selector, random numbers in selector

Tags: jquery, random, numbers, selector

How can I handle random numbers in selector?

This syntax is from Power Automate but it uses Jquery selectors.

This is the selector that I have : `input[Id="SalesLine_SalesPrice_2437_0_0_input"]`
but I figured that `_2437_` Might be any number, for example `1`, `25`, `102`, `2467`, `35697`

So how I can handle that random number?

Comment: Can you add a class and simplify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you need you can use a combination of the 'attribute begins with' and 'attribute ends with' selectors:

```
$('input[id^="SalesLine_SalesPrice_"][id$="_0_0_input"]')
```

Or the 'attribute contains' selector:

```
$('input[id*="SalesLine_SalesPrice"]')
```

Or `filter()` with a regex:

```
$('input').filter((i, el) => /SalesLine_SalesPrice_\d{1,5}_0_0_input/i.test(el.id));
```

It would depend on your use case which is the most appropriate.

That being said, if you want to select multiple of these elements with dynamic `id` attributes, then the best approach would be to just add a common class to them all.

```
$('input.common-class')
```